# Two drop down list values to re-direct to specific URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

Wondering if anyone can help. I am trying to create a way of the user filling in two two drop values and depending on those values, got to a specific URL.

For example, they would pick what subject they want to study in the first drop down and the then in the 2nd drop down they select there date. Depending on the date they pick, depends on which URL to send them too.

This is the code I have put together and here is a page I have tried the code on, but when I press submit, nothing happens.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function url() {
        var subject = $("#subject").val();
        var preferred-date = $("#preferred-date").val();
        if (subject == "" || preferred-date == ""){
        
        alert("Please select which subject you would like to study and your desired date you would like to come in and enrol");
        }
            if (subject != "animal-management" && preferred-date == "25thaug"){
                window.location.href = 'https://www.google.co.uk'; }
            if (subject != "animal-management" && preferred-date == "26thaug"){
                window.location.href = 'https://www.sthelens.ac.uk'; }
            if (subject != "art-design" && preferred-date == "25thaug"){
                window.location.href = 'https://shc-adult-art-25th.eventbrite.co.uk/';}
            if (subject != "art-design" && preferred-date == "26thaug"){
                window.location.href = 'https://knowsleycollege.ac.uk/';}
    }
</script>
```

```
<select id="subject">
<option value="">Please select which subject you would like to study with us:</option>
<option value="animal-management">Animal Management</option>
<option value="art-design">Art and Design</option>
</select>
<select id="preferred-date">
<option value="">Please select what date you would like to come in and enrol</option>
<option value="25thaug">Tuesday 25th August 2020</option>
<option value="26thaug">Wednesday 26th August 2020</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="url()"/>
```

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance
Sam

Comment: Any errors in the console? I'm not sure a variable name with a dash is valid?

Comment: Have input type as button, as it seems you want function to be called  on it's click.

Comment: @Asutosh `<input type="submit"` *is* a button

Comment: you have to prevent default action in that case.

Comment: As in the comment above `preferred-date` is not a valid variable name and this will *very* quickly be shown in the console / any IDE that you're using.   Always check the console for errors.  Your code "works" with this fixed, though your logic of `subject != x` is somewhat confusing and will fail if you have 3 options.  https://jsfiddle.net/gq0osxk2/

Answer (score 0):

As the comments are saying, there is a lot of incorrect syntax in your code.  Mostly around "preferred-date".  Checkout out https://jsfiddle.net/furm49d3/

```
function url() {

    var subject = $("#subject").val();
    var preferred_date = $("#preferred-date").val();
    if (subject == "" || preferred_date == ""){
    
    alert("Please select which subject you would like to study and your desired date you would like to come in and enroll");
    }
        if (subject != "animal-management" && preferred_date == "25thaug"){
            window.location.href = 'https://www.google.co.uk'; }
        if (subject != "animal-management" && preferred_date == "26thaug"){
            window.location.href = 'https://www.sthelens.ac.uk'; }
        if (subject != "art-design" && preferred_date == "25thaug"){
            window.location.href = 'https://shc-adult-art-25th.eventbrite.co.uk/';}
        if (subject != "art-design" && preferred_date == "26thaug"){
            window.location.href = 'https://knowsleycollege.ac.uk/';}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all of your suggestions. I'll be honest, I tweaked some code that I found online. So it isn't my original code, but I take on board all your comments, and will give it a go now. Thank you for your quick responses.